# Add my password as part of the script or argument?

Tags: password, scripts

```
==============
#shell script
sudo ls
==============
```

When I execute it, script asks for the password. I would like to add my password as part of the script or argument. How can I do it?

Comment: See if http://askubuntu.com/questions/52212/what-is-the-least-insecure-way-to-store-a-password-that-is-used-by-a-script helps

Answer (score 0):

```
echo password | sudo -S command
```

So you pipe your password to sudo, and the -S command makes sudo read your password from the standard input instead of the terminal.

Comment: Of course, this is a big security flaw, as you store your password in plain text.

Comment: Well then this will help you http://askubuntu.com/questions/291520/could-up-arrow-key-in-terminal-is-a-risk-when-encrypting-using-7z/291576#291576

Comment: If you want a different syntax: sudo -S <<<'password' command

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small script. It will ask your password on a pop-up window when you execute the script.

[image: pop-up window asking password]

```bash
#!/bin/bash

ENTRY=$(zenity --password)

if [ $ENTRY ]; then
    echo -e "$(echo $ENTRY)" | sudo -S date
else
    echo "abort"
fi 
sudo ls
```

And it is quite safe as it is not storing your password anywhere or allowing to display the characters while you input your password.